# Hibernate: Remove Item From Collection Without Initialazing

Tags: hibernate, collections, many-to-many

I'm having troubles with an Hibernate Many To Many Collection.
When i try to remove an item from the relation, hibernate loads the entire collection (is too big).
Here is an example: supose A has many to many relation with B

```
public class A {

@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
  CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "a_b", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id", unique = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id", unique = true) })
@Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = AscBComparator.class)
private List<B> listB;

public List<B> getListB() {
   return listB;
}

}

// in other part

A.getListB().remove(concreteB);
```

When the program reach to A.getListB() hibernate loads the entire collection.
Is there anyway to avoid this? I just want to remove the row from the join table.

I tried with: 
@BatchSize to limit de collection size but finally i understood that it doesn't work as i expected.

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA), didn't work

Comment: why not delete directly B ?

Comment: because B is still part of my domain, i can't delete it. Just B is no longer related to A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the relation between A and B is bidirectional, fetch B, then update it change the value of its A, make this value null or another value. 
some thing like this :

```
B b = bService.getBById(id);
b.setA(null); // or b.setA(anotherValueOfA);
bService.update(b);
```

it should work

Comment: The relation isn't bidirectional, in the domain it doesn't make any sense to navigate from B to A. But if i don't find another solution i will take this path in order to improve performance. Another idea is making the delete sql statement.

Comment: I implemented the biderectional, but when i save B it doesn't delete de row in the join table. Any idea?

Comment: I realiced that the owner of the relation is A, that's why i can't save the changes. I don't think i can change the ownership :(

Comment: If B is the ownership this is the solution :)